# Class member initialization failed for singleton mode

Tags: c++, class, singleton

I'm writing a class using singleton mode. The code is as below:

**A.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    static A get_instance();
    static A* get_instance_ptr();
    void init(int i);
    void print_data(void);
private:
    static A* instance_ptr;
    int data;
};

A* A::instance_ptr = NULL;

A* A::get_instance_ptr()
{
    if (NULL == instance_ptr) {
        instance_ptr = new A();
    }
    return instance_ptr;
}

A A::get_instance()
{
    return *get_instance_ptr();
}

void A::init(int i) 
{
    data = i;
    std::cout << "In A::init, data = " << data << std::endl;
}

void A::print_data(void)
{
    std::cout << "In A::print_data, data = " << data << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A::get_instance().init(42);
    A::get_instance().print_data();
    return 0;
}
```

The principle is to initialize `data` in `A::init()` and print it in `A::print_data`. But the output is:

```
In A::init, data = 42
In A::print_data, data = 0
```

It seems the `data` initialization didn't work. But if I change the initialization in `main` to:

```
A::get_instance_ptr()->init(42);
```

The output is as expected:

```
In A::init, data = 42
In A::print_data, data = 42
```

So the question is, why the member initialization failed in the first try?

Comment: Please do not start programming using globals (or the anti-pattern singleton). Also avoid pointers

Comment: Instead of "globals" and singletons, rather use static members/functions of a class without any instance. E.g. for configuration parameters, for moving out constants like string literals, a logging mechanism and so on...

Comment: Singletons are generally a bad idea, especially in C++. A copyable singleton that requires manual initialisation is so far beyond the realm of bad ideas that you can almost see sanity on the horizon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the return type of `get_instance` is `A` instead of the correct `A&` and therefore a copy of your "singleton" is returned each time you call it. The `init` call operates on a copy of your original object, then `print_data` operates on a different copy. When all is said and done, `main` has managed to create three copies of the singleton.

Singletons that can be copied are not really singletons. You should do the bare minimum to prevent copies (declaring private ctors and assignment operator and not defining them).